# Solrj - cannot inherit from final class error due to HTTPSolrServer

Tags: java, maven, solr, solrj

I have been using Solr version 4.10.2. I added solrj version 4.10.2 by using maven (pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

These are maven dependencies that are installed:

```
solr-solrj-4.10.2.jar
httpclient-4.3.1.jar
httpcore-4.3.jar
httpmime-4.3.1.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.7.jar
noggit-0.5.jar
```

When I define solr http path, l get and exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.createHttpParams(DefaultHttpClient.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getParams(AbstractHttpClient.java:447)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.setFollowRedirects(HttpClientUtil.java:260)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientConfigurer.configure(HttpClientConfigurer.java:60)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.configureClient(HttpClientUtil.java:142)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.createClient(HttpClientUtil.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<init>(HttpSolrServer.java:168)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.<init>(HttpSolrServer.java:141)
    at addIndex.main(addIndex.java:10)
```

This is how I define solr path:

`HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");` or

```
HttpSolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1");
```

Is there another way to make a connection with java project? What is the reason that I get this exception?

Comment: I am working on Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're connecting to Solr (and using SolrJ as the client library), you're [supposed to instantiate `HttpSolrClient`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Using+SolrJ):

```
String urlString = "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1";
SolrClient solr = new HttpSolrClient(urlString);
```

BTW: Anchors in URLs (such as #foo) is meant for clients only (such as browsers), and are not meant to be (and thus, isn't, usually) transmitted as part of the request.

Comment: I changed with yours and am getting the same exception. I added a String variable, removed # from the URL. By the way, I cannot import SolrClient. It does not exist. http://postimg.org/image/4nxnnz27v/

Comment: It's in the [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient.html) package (the link is to the actual implementation).

Comment: Thank you. Version 4.10.2 does not support SolrClient package, so I changed the version as 5.4.0 and it works now.